# sql server evaluating one to many rows with no duplicates

Tags: sql-server, join, row

humbly I ask for help with the next problem.

I have this one very simple. Don't know how to describe it by words so I'll do with an image.

table services

```
PERSONID     Service_id          chargeamount
1               3                 20.50
2               4                 80.50
3               5                 78.80
```

table charges

```
service_id     payed          extracharges
3               true              20.50
4               true              80.50
3               false             78.80
```

if there is any unpayed extracharge it must show true or false , and if the service id do not match in the second table it must be shown in the query with null values or other calculated value

Something like this

```
PERSONID     Service_id          chargeamount                        payed
1               3                 20.50                              false
2               4                 80.50                              true
3               5                 78.80                              null
```

but extra rows of the same row are not allowed like the ones created by joins.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SERVICES](
    [personid] [int] NULL,
    [service_id] [int] NULL,
    [chargeamount] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


insert into services (personid,service_id,chargeamount) values ( 1,3  ,20);
insert into services (personid,service_id,chargeamount) values ( 2,4  ,20);
insert into services (personid,service_id,chargeamount) values ( 3,5 ,20);



SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[charges](
    [payed] [bit] NULL,
    [service_id] [int] NULL,
    [extracharges] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into services (service_id,payed,extracharges) values ( 3,true,20.50);
insert into services (service_id,payed,extracharges) values ( 3,false,78.80);
insert into services (service_id,payed,extracharges) values ( 4,false,80.50);
```

Comment: Why does `Service_id` 3 evaluate to `false` under `payed`?

Comment: I think it's a typo, the third row in table charges should show 5, not 3

Comment: it's one to many relationship , i intend to evaluate is there is a unpayed charge in charges table;The resultset row will be shown as false otherwise it will say true

Comment: because if there is a single charge wich is not payed this service won't be forgiven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple left join on `service_id`. When there is at least one row with `payed` = `false`, `false` is shown. Otherwise `true` or `null` is shown, respectively.

```
select s.*, case min(c.payed) when 1 then 'true' when 0 then 'false' else 'null' end
from services s
left join charges c on c.service_id = s.service_id
group by s.personid, s.service_id, s.chargeamount
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21fde/2/0)

Comment: nice try friend but still having duplicate rows if i have in table charges id 3 a payment with true and another with false the final resultset shows a row wich service id payed is true and another false i hope you can help me. I'm very greatful with your efforts

Comment: @GoAntonio I missed that last part. I hope, this is correct now.

Comment: it says min can't be applied to boolean data type case min(c.payed) Or did you meant case min(c.extracharge) ? i think this is impossible i've never seen such thing as i want to realize do you think its possible?

Comment: @GoAntonio Look at the SQLFiddle. I have used an int, not a boolean data type. If you have a create table and data statements, put it in a SQLFiddle, so we can talk about the same data structure.

Comment: truly it is , sorry i apologise . missread the int values instead the keywords true and false thank you very much! you saved me a lot of precious time